# My python script is consuming twice the amount of cpu credits per hour on t2.medium compared to t2.small

Tags: python, multithreading, amazon-ec2

I have a python script that runs a single process with ~150 threads. On Ubuntu Server 16.04 t2.small instance type it runs at around 30% CPUUtilization. Since it has to run constantly at that rate and the baseline performance of t2.small is 20%, I decided to move to t2.medium (whose baseline performance is 40%). However, when I run the script on t2.medium, the script starts consuming around 30% from each of the two computational units (for a total of 60%), hence pushing me above the 40% baseline.

From my understanding, a python script running a single process (albeit on multiple threads) doesn't use more than 1 CPU core (in this case it's virtual). And, in any case, if my script is running at 30% cpu usage on t2.small, why doesn't it do just the same on one computational unit on t2.medium, regardless of the availability of a second computational unit? What am I missing here?

EDIT: I decided to experiment a little bit and I cloned my instance to create a t2.micro, t2.small, and t2.medium instances of the same image. When I started the same script on each instance, this is my CPUCreditUsage on each:

[image: CPUCreditUsage]

The colors are as follows:

Blue: t2.micro
Orange: t2.small
Green: t2.medium

As expected, the t2.medium is consuming twice the amount of credits, so I am really losing any advantage of using medium over small.

Comment: Are you using the same number of threads?

Comment: Yes, I only upgraded the instance from t2.small to t2.medium and ran the same script.

Comment: That doesn't mean that the number of threads is the same. Some libraries create a different number of threads depending on the number of available cores.

Comment: Gotcha. But I'm not using any libraries that create threads and I'm manually creating all threads in my code using the threading module.

Comment: I can confirm the number of threads is the same in both instances.

Comment: You should be able to check what's running using top, run top, press 1 (to see multiple CPUs) and take a look how both CPUs are used. And I would do the same on the t2.small just to have some reference data.

Comment: I checked with htop and I found something strange. In t2.small the number of threads is variable around 150, whereas in t2.medium the same number fluctuates around 280. Is it possible that the two units are literally duplicating each others' work? Why would that be happening?

Comment: *"Is it possible that the two units are literally duplicating each others' work?"*  The two CPUs? No, there's no reason that would happen.

Comment: @LyubenLaskin at the risk of asking a ridiculous question, are you sure you're not getting twice as much actual work done per unit of time?  A process will consume 100% of the available CPU cycles *unless* it has to block to wait for resources -- typically meaning the disk or the network (including waiting for responses from remote systems/APIs).  The fact that yours isn't means that it depends on something other than raw CPU capacity, and doubling your instance size approximately doubles everything -- including the bandwidth of the network connection (which is also where disk access happens).

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot you're right, I am receiving real time data through websocket connections (each connection is handled by a separate thread).

Could you explain a little further why doubling my instance size doubles everything else? I am trying to make a decision regarding the instance type and I'm not sure I understand the root of the problem.

The reason I chose a T2 type is precisely because I am not utilizing 100% of the CPU power. But was my decision correct or should I perhaps use a C4 instance type? Or perhaps a T2 unlimited option would be cheaper?

Comment: Also, I'm still not sure why the number of threads roughly doubles on t2.medium. Isn't it supposed to be a fixed number, given that I am manually starting a fixed number of threads in my code?

Comment: @LyubenLaskin doubling the size of an instance (e.g. t2.small to t2.medium) doubles your number of vCPUs, the amount of memory, and the speed of your network connection (and thereby, the amount of hard drive throughput you can achieve) because that's how AWS designed the service tiers.  I was speculating that your code could get more work done due to some relief of whatever congestion was blocking its performance, before... but it sounds like there are architectural aspects that only you can explain.